# Differences in .htaccess parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, get, difference

I have the following .htaccess :

```
Options FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ index.php?test=$1 [B,NE,QSA]
```

Then i have the following index.php :

```
print_r($_GET);
```

The result of http://localhost/test/directeur+R%26D?test2=directeur+R%26D is :

```
 Array ( [test] => directeur+R&D [test2] => directeur R&D )
```

Why test and test2 are different please ? I would like them to have the same value.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to have the response :

`Array ( [test] => directeur R&D [test2] => directeur R&D )`

Answer (score 0):

With `B` flag in place `+` won't be converted to space in URI. You will need an additional rule to convert `+` to space first.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# convert + to space in URI
RewriteRule ^([^+]+)\+(.*)$ "$1 $2" [L]

# now your original rule
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ index.php?test=$1 [B,L,QSA]
```

Now your test URL will give you this `$_GET` array:

```
Array
(
    [test] => directeur R&D
    [test2] => directeur R&D
)
```

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution was to rebuild the $_GET variable with $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].